# Status Code of AggregateException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am working on mobile app using xamarin forms. I have used the web api for post and get request etc. In some cases exception is thrown, im not able to get the status code. Is there any solution to get the status of error? Status Codes like 400,401,402 etc.

Answer (score 0):

An AggregateException is thrown if more then one error occurred. Look in the `InnerExceptions` property of the AggregateException to see the "real" errors.

Comment: I need to get the status of error, i know how to check the detail of error using *InnerExceptions*

Comment: Sorry, the innerExceptions should provide you with the same informations..

Comment: Thanks for replay @Glenn, but InnerException does not provide Status Code enum for implement check. I have used **ex.InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault().Message** for display alert.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I had the same problem regarding connected services.

For me the solution was to cast InnerException if it was of type SwaggerException and to do stuff depending on the StatusCode (like translating those codes into exceptions e.g.).

```
if (e.InnerException == null || typeof(SwaggerException) != e.InnerException.GetType())
    throw new Exception(e.Message);

var ie = (SwaggerException) e.InnerException;

switch (ie.StatusCode) {
    case 400:
        throw new ArgumentException(ie.Response);
    case 404:
        throw new KeyNotFoundException(ie.Response);
    default:
        throw new Exception(ie.Response);
}
```